# How to create new array using element of existing array?

Tags: javascript

I am having JSON array in that one object contain many keyvaluepair records, but I want only few key records. how to create new array using keys?

```
array = [
{
 airlineName: "Airline 1",
 hotelName: "Hotel 1 ", 
 airportId: "456",
 checkInDate: "17 SEP 1998",
 bookingStatus: "B"
},
{
airlineName: "Airline 2",
 hotelName: "Hotel 1", 
 airportId: "123",
 checkInDate: "7 AUG 1998",
 bookingStatus: "P"
 }
]
```

I want array like this for some operation:

```
array = [
{
 airlineName: "Airline 1",
 hotelName: "Hotel 1 ", 
 bookingStatus: "B"
},
{
airlineName: "Airline 2",
 hotelName: "Hotel 1", 
 bookingStatus: "P"
 }
]
```

Comment: You could use [`Array.Map`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

Comment: destructuring https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single line working solution:

```
this.array.map(x => ({airlineName: x.airlineName, hotelName: x.hotelName, bookingStatus: x.bookingStatus}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var result = [];
this.array.forEach(item => {
  result.push({
    airlineName: item.airlineName,
    hotelName: item.hotelName,
    bookingStatus: item.bookingStatus
  });
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utizsa?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Isn't that just a truthy expression resulting in an array of booleans?

Comment: Not the most elegant way of doing it but it is working

Comment: @Exomus I agree :)

Answer (score 1):

Use map operator:

```js
const newArray = this.array.map(element => {
    return {
      airlineName: element.airlineName,
      hotelName: element.hotelName,
      bookingStatus: element.bookingStatus
    };
  });
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nn9qf4)

Answer (score 0):

That's what `map` does.

```js
const array = [{
    airlineName: "Airline 1",
    hotelName: "Hotel 1 ",
    airportId: "456",
    checkInDate: "17 SEP 1998",
    bookingStatus: "B"
  },
  {
    airlineName: "Airline 2",
    hotelName: "Hotel 1",
    airportId: "123",
    checkInDate: "7 AUG 1998",
    bookingStatus: "P"
  }
]


const pickValues = ({
  airlineName,
  hotelName,
  bookingStatus
}) => ({
  airlineName,
  hotelName,
  bookingStatus
});

console.log(array.map(pickValues));
```